# How to decode an escaped UTF-8 string?

Tags: gtk, printf, vala

I'm using Vala and GTK but I think someone may be able to help without either of these things being relevant. Using Vala I can access some C functions like printf and if necessary create bindings to anything else.

GTK's Entry widget escapes text and when the string is used internally it works fine. But if I try to put it into an output stream crème brûlée is escaped like cr\303\250me br\303\273l\303\251e.

Using printf, any of the GTK functions, or anything Vala supports, how can I unescape these characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to see the string as a list of Unicode codepoints, you can use [`string.get_next_char`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/string.get_next_char) to iterate over the string one codepoint at a time. An example is in the reference.

If you want graphemes, I do not know of a way to do this using GLib/Vala.

Comment: The problem is all the GTK functions just return strings escaped with slashes. Using entry.get_text() or entry.buffer.text the text is literally slashes and numbers not UTF-8 characters encoded in the string. Its escape sequences.

 22, c
 23, r
 24, \
 25, 3
 26, 0
 27, 3
 28, \
 29, 2
 30, 5
 31, 0
 32, m
 33, e
 34,  
 35, b
 36, r
 37, \
 38, 3
 39, 0
 40, 3
 41, \
 42, 2
 43, 7
 44, 3
 45, l
 46, \
 47, 3
 48, 0
 49, 3
 50, \
 51, 2
 52, 5
 53, 1

Comment: What line are you using to print the string returned by `entry.get_text()`? That shouldn't be happening...

Comment: Try it. Paste crème brûlé into a Entry. And just printf it to the screen. It will be encoded like that. All I'm doing is sending it to a DataOutputStream but if I print it at any point before then that is how it is encoded.

Comment: I can't reproduce. [Here's the program I tried.](http://pastie.org/10273527) What are your terminal settings? Mine has `$LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8` and `$LC_COLLATE` set to `C`.

Comment: You were right. I had an escape method that I was glossing over. Thanks for your help. I wasted all day on this.

Comment: Good to know. Best of luck with the rest of this project!